# Android MediaExtractor fails to return sample

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, video-editing, mediaextractor

I am trying to decode a video onto a surface in Android using `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor`.

To start with, I use the `setDataSource(context, uri, null)` method on the `MediaExtractor` object (`extractor` below) to set the data source uri. The uri comes from the Android file picker for videos. This call doesn't seem to throw any exceptions.

In the `onInputBufferAvailable()` call from the decoder, I then read a new sample from the extractor but the `extractor.readSampleData(..)` call randomly fails to read the correct data and starts returning buffers of size -1. Ideally, the size should only be -1 when the whole file has been read. Moreover, once the extractor starts returning -1, it never returns the correct sample however many times I call `extractor.advance()`.

I also observe this warning message in the logs whenever this issue happens:

```
W/NuMediaExtractor: read on track 0 failed with error -2147483646
```

Code:

```
object : MediaCodec.Callback() {
    override fun onInputBufferAvailable(codec: MediaCodec, index: Int) {
        val buffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index)!!
        try {
            val size = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0)
            if (size > 0) {
                decoder.queueInputBuffer(
                    index,
                    0,
                    size,
                    extractor.sampleTime,
                    sampleFlags
                )
                extractor.advance()
            } else if (size == 0) {
                Timber.d("Size 0 sample received from extractor")
            } else if (size == -1) {
            // Size is -1 when no more samples are available                     
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
             Timber.e(exception)
        }
    }
```

This doesn't happen all the time but frequent enough. So far, I have only observed this on the Android 9 OS.

Edit 1: To prevent a race condition, I save the free input buffers into a blocking queue. A while loop then picks up these buffers from the queue.

```
    private val inputBuffersQueue: BlockingQueue<InputBufferData> = LinkedBlockingQueue()


    private fun feedSamplesToDecoder(extractor: MediaExtractor, trimStartUs: Long, trimEndUs: Long) {
        inputHandler.post {
            while (!wasEOSInputBufferFed) {
                val inputBuffer = inputBuffersQueue.take()
                val decoder = inputBuffer.codec
                val index = inputBuffer.index
                val sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer.codec.getInputBuffer(inputBuffer.index)!!, 0)
                if (sampleSize > 0) {
                    val sampleTime = extractor.sampleTime
                    lastSampleTimestampUs = sampleTime
                    val sampleFlags = extractor.sampleFlags
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(
                        index,
                        0,
                        sampleSize,
                        sampleTime - trimStartUs,
                        sampleFlags
                    )
                    extractor.advance()
                } else if (sampleSize == 0) {
                    Timber.d("Size 0 sample received from extractor")
                } else {
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(
                        index,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "This doesn't happen all the time but frequent enough" may hint for a race condition.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I thought the same so updated the code to ensure that the exractor.readSampleData() method is never called concurrently. Updating the question with the code.

Comment: Try to change condition to `if (sampleSize >= 0) {` because sample size of zero may be valid and you still need to `advance`.

Comment: Checking that out @PointerNull

Comment: @PointerNull Useful hint, thanks! but doesn't quite solve the issue. There is another warning that shows in the logs whenever this happens. Added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First search google for "NuMediaExtractor: read on track 0 failed with error -2147483646".
I see 2 results: [A](https://forum.unity.com/threads/looping-video-not-working-on-android-mp4.591766/), [B](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-video-freezes-while-playing-when-a-video-is-loaded-from-streamingassets-folder)

They write about bug fixed in Android 10. Something about too big bitrate and need to re-encode video.

Still I'd suggest to find possible workaround. Instead of using [setDataSource(Context, Uri, Map)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaExtractor?hl=en#setdatasource_1), try to call [setDataSource(MediaDataSource)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaExtractor?hl=en#setdatasource), implement your own [MediaDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaDataSource), just 2 methods: `getSize` where you return size of file, and `readAt` where you read from file completely entire requested size (don't return after partial reads that InputStream sometimes does; partial read is allowed only at end of file). You can debug this by loading fixed file using [RandomAccessFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile), and if you see that bug is resolved, you can implement own MediaDataSource reading from content:// scheme (which is returned by system file picker).

You can log reads in your MediaDataSource, and compare the log with successful run on another device where bug doesn't happen (test on same file). Maybe you'll see that Android requests different ranges on Android 9, or it requests same reads but still fails. Then that's Android bug and you probably can't fix that.

Hopefully this helps you to get closer to finding reason of problem, or even fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the ideas! I will try them and be back to report :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the root problem of yours is the uri. My suggestion is to reparse it into something more common that widely accepted by many apps.
For example is your uri looks like this (starts with content://) `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3356`, try to change it into `file:///storage/emulated/0/document/3356`.  `com.android.providers.downloads.documents` is a package name and `document/3356` is a file path. You can get `/storage/emulated/0` via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method. Then use `Uri.parse("string")` to get a uri instance.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/document/3356");
```

Comment: That's nonsense, `content://` is preferred on Android over `file://`, and some files are not even stored locally (may be served from network), and still system file picker can return them. `MediaExtractor` reads from content scheme just fine.